# Periodic $H^1((0,2\pi)),L^2((0,2\pi)),L^1((0,2\pi))$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $a\in L^1((0,2\pi))$,$u,v\in H^1((0,2\pi))$ such that : $u(0)=u(2\pi),v(0)=v(2\pi)$.

Can we prove that : $$\int_{0}^{2\pi}(a(x))^2u(x)v(x)dx<\infty, ?$$

I really don't know this is right or wrong .

Comment: Taking $u \equiv 1$, $v \equiv 1$ and $a \in L^1$ such that $a \notin L^2$ (e.g. $a(x) = x^{-1/2}$), we see that this is not true.